# PHP Detect 1 or more unicode spaces only

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match

I have searched in vain to find a fix for this issue.  I have an editable field in a web page that contains a user entered space. When I copy the space and enter it into a program called IVI32 which I guess you would call a Unicode text program, I get the following info.

The space character is defined as FFFE2000. I need to detect when this field has one or more of these spaces and nothing else. I have tried the following with preg_match:

```
'/\s+/u'
'/^[0 :-]+$/ '
'/\A\s*\z/'
```

Nothing works and I am completely stumped.  Any help from some Unicode experts out there will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think `FFFE2000` resolves to any sensible character. Just try `var_dump(bin2hex($string))` and show us the result, together with what you expect there to be.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in my code which was preventing anything from working properly (the product of no time off!). Here's what works for anyone else who might want to detect if an element contains only whitespace that cannot be eliminated by php trim();

```
if(!preg_match('/\\s/', $test_string)):-do something-
if(!preg_match('/\s+/u', $test_string)):-do something-
if(!preg_match('/[\pZ\pC]+/u', $test_string)):-do something-
```

For anyone who is interested the space is pasted immediately after the end of this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
preg_match('/^ +$/', $subject);
```

Match a single or more spaces? Because \s will also match nonbreaking spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work.  I did find something that works (finally!) so I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
/\p{WhiteSpace}/
```

Comment: Thanks, but as written this generates the following error:Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p